# How to fetch ID from database if particular column has both value

Tags: mysql, sql, between, zen-cart, having-clause

Database columns, Now i want to get those Product IDs only those having OPTIONS_VALUES_ID (12 and 31)

[image: Database Image]

```
  SELECT DISTINCT  pa.products_id,options_values_id,options_id , COUNT(options_values_id) FROM products_attributes pa WHERE 
            pa.products_id IN (3331,3452,3455) AND pa.options_values_id IN (12,31) 
            GROUP BY pa.products_id
            HAVING (pa.options_values_id) >  0
```

Above Query Result
[image: Above Query Result]

I could not figure out how to get only those **products id** which having define **options_value_id** by user

Comment: Can you clarify your question ?

Comment: So what's **wrong** with your results? Are you expecting all rows for an ID if at least one row has that options_values_id?

Comment: I am not good in mysql, I want those id which having both options-values-id, Currently it get those which having options-values-id 31 or 12, i want the condition to get product having 31 and 12. U can check example on site which i am working on Price sorting http://junoon2.co.uk.dnpserver.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=21_23&show=&psort=&psort=&attval%5B%5D=12&attval%5B%5D=31

Comment: Can you please tell us your expected output..

Comment: In assuming your desired output is your selection of rows in red, I am not sure it can be done with a single SQL query.  You would need to input the results of one query into another query

Comment: Currenty it get 3 rows but only ID 3452 has both option_values_id. so it is not working properly. I need to get only those Ids that having both option_values_id in a column

Comment: In Front-end, if Green color is selected and Size is select. It should Show only Green color dresses only. Please Check the Link below:

http://junoon2.co.uk.dnpserver.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=21_23&show=&psort=&psort=&attval%5B%5D=12&attval%5B%5D=31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you meant...

```
SELECT products_id,COUNT(options_values_id) 
FROM products_attributes WHERE 
options_values_id in(12,31)
GROUP BY products_id
having COUNT(options_values_id)>=2
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58b29/2)

Comment: Yes this I wanted.

SELECT products_id,COUNT(options_values_id) 
FROM products_attributes WHERE 
options_values_id IN(12,31) AND products_id IN (3331,3452,3455)
GROUP BY products_id
HAVING COUNT(options_values_id)=2

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `DISTINCT` because `GROUP BY` will remove duplicate values of your `pa.products_id`

```
SELECT pa.products_id,options_values_id,options_id , COUNT(options_values_id) 
FROM products_attributes pa 
WHERE pa.options_values_id IN (12,31) 
GROUP BY pa.products_id
```

hope this will help you...!

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants..As this gives the same result as the query posted by OP..

Comment: Nope this is not What i want....! Thanks for help. I want get Product Id which having both option values in a column

Comment: In Front-end, if Green color is selected and Size is select. It should Show only Green color dresses wHICH HAVING GIVEN SIZE. Please Check the Link below:

http://junoon2.co.uk.dnpserver.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=21_23&show=&psort=&psort=&attval%5B%5D=12&attval%5B%5D=31

Comment: you mean that you want details of those items whose having both the pa.options_values_id ie. 12 and 32 right ?

Comment: SELECT pa.products_id,options_values_id,options_id , COUNT(options_values_id) 
FROM products_attributes pa 
WHERE pa.options_values_id IN (12,31)  HAVING pa.products_id IN (3331,3452,3455)
GROUP BY pa.products_id